# Eigenvectorcomponentvalues over Eigenvectorkomponents form a polynomial

Tags: matrices

I had to find the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of a $50\times 50$ matrix of the form

$$ A = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
2 & -1 & && \\ 
-1 &2 &-1 && \\ 
& \ddots & \ddots &\ddots & \\ 
&&-1&2&-1 \\ 
&&& -1& 2
\end{pmatrix}
$$

and plot the values of the vector components over the vector components itself for the four smallest eigenvalues $\lambda$. What I got was the following graph, which suprised me:

[eigenvectorcomponentsvalues over eigenvectorcomponents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOg4T.png)

The $\lambda's$ are the eigenvalues. I do not understand, why the graphs have the form of sinus-like functions and which kind of polynomials these are. My supervisor already said, that these are no trigonometric functions.  Does one know a reason for that?